# How to select same colums in each line in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

Suppose that there are only ten lines in a file. The content I want to select is shown in the picture below. They have the same start column position and end column position.

I already know several ways to obtain this:

1. ctrl+click to select the start position in each line, then use shift+right to expand;
2. ctrl+click to select the start position in the first line,, use ctrl+alt+down to expand,then use shift+right to expand;
3. hold shift and right mouse to select the content;

Either works fine on it. but when there are thousands of lines, this could be a very hard task. I'll spend a long time to scroll so may lines.

Is there a better way to solve this? thanks!

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all lines
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all lines independently
3. <kbd>Home</kbd> to deselect all text and return to the beginning of each line
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> until I'm at the start of the data
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> until the portion is selected.

From there, you can copy or edit as needed.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how I would do it. This works well for me with large files